# How to access value from react-native-cn-richtext-editor

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have successfully implemented `react-native-cn-richtext-editor` with limited toolbar functions.

I want to know that, how to get value (text that we have typed) from editor.

I am new in RN, have tried to get value but didn't get success. How can I resolve this issue, as I want to sent this text to server and then do further process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution of above question.

convert the value in HTML with convertToHtmlString write following command,

```
let html = convertToHtmlString(this.state.value)
```

for more details refer this [github link](https://github.com/imnapo/react-native-cn-richtext-editor/issues/51#issuecomment-648102203)

Answer (score 0):

In given example of this library there is method onValueChange on change the content object is present in value and to extract the value below example is there

```
onValueChanged = (value) => {

       console.log(value[0].content[0].text)
    }
```

Comment: I want typed value like this, 
<div><p><span>This is </span><span style="font-weight: bold;">bold</span><span> and </span><span style="font-style: italic;">italic </span><span>text</span></p></div>
does it possible? so backend team can view same text in web as well.

Comment: this command giving simple text only, without formation/decoration element.

Comment: could you please help me get value from editer with HTML tags so I can sent it to db with same? I am stuck add looking for solution from last 2 days. Please help me.
appreciating your help, because of this only I got stuck. 

**Input String:** This is **bold** and _italic_ text

**output should be something like this or in format of editor:** 
`<div><p><span>This is </span><span style="font-weight: bold;">bold</span><span> and </span><span style="font-style: italic;">italic </span><span>text</span></p></div>`

Comment: In this library u will not get the html friendly response. U will have to convert it manually as per response received. As this library gives you each line as seperate node with its style applied in it >>>>>>>response>>>>>>>>>
https://imgur.com/bes6uv4

Comment: Here is a sample example  created roughly which may help you: >>>>>>>>>>>> https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/lonely-raisins

Comment: thank you, will look into above link and update you.